# Reports and Dashboard guru?

Tags: reporting, administration, lightning

I'm a fairly new developer/admin (1.5 yrs in the role).  I would love to focus on learning apex and building lightning components but the majority of my time making small edits but mainly creating reports and dashboards for the different departments at my firm.  Not a hard job creating reports/dashboards but when I present the teams with my creations of the report or dashboard, it's like I blew their minds......  I get all sorts of praise and thanks and it feels good but makes me wonder...... Is there a such thing as a Reports and Dashboard guru?   or do many of you "train" your end users how to create reports and dashboards on their own.

I would love to hear the experiences.

thanks in advance.

Chad

Comment: Personally I would train up some super users leaving me time to code :)

Comment: I think that a lot of people would name Steve Molis as a reporting guru. I always try and train some super users within the organisation to look after most reporting as they have detailed business knowledge about what they are looking for.

Comment: Most would be amazed at the response that visualization of data gets in a business that has not had easy access to this prior. Many mid to smaller sized organizations have either limited or difficult to work with resources when it comes to reports or data visualization. Although it's easy to ride that train for a very long time, i find more value in empowering some "super users" to take the role while i work on even bigger things that will "blow minds". Salesforce is a vast platform, so don't spend too much time on one piece. If you can master one and tier it to someone else, do it and grow :)

Comment: thank you guys for your encouraging comments.  I will begin either finding or creating Super Users.  I work for a large company and i can see how in the future I can get overly tasked with dashboard or report request...